# display felx problem when resizing the page

Tags: html, css

Hello every one I wrote this code in HTML:

```css
.wrapper2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding:20px;
    background: #1f3138;
    color: white;
}
.wrapper2 h2{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wrapper2 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.p2{
    margin-top: -1em;
}
.wrapper2 i{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
  <h2 class="footer"> <a href="#"> Content <br><p>Lorem, ipsum.</p><br><p class="p2">Lorem, ipsum.</p></a></h2>
  <h2 class="footer"><a href="#"> information <br><p>Lorem, ipsum.</p><br><p class="p2">Lorem, ipsum.</p></a></h2>
  <h2 class="footer"><a href="#"> legal <br><p>Lorem, ipsum.</p><br><p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></a></h2>
  <h2 class="footer"><a href="#"> help <br><p>Lorem, ipsum.</p><br><p class="p2">Lorem, ipsum.</p></a></h2>
  <h2 class="footer"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>3-6000-0000
  -6000-000-0000</h2>
  <h2 class="footer6"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>67700 Dagenham St
  England, GB</h2>
</div>
```

I made it display flex when I resize the page lower than 1920px width the h2 getinng close to each other and it is not making the space between can any one help please.

Answer (score 0):

The space between flex items is distributed accordingly, so when the screen size becomes less the space between the items will become less.

Try using a  the gap property on the flex parent (if your browser support allows) or margin left/right on the items to force spacing even at lower screen sizes.

Comment: thank you so much that helped a lot i edited the margin and it woks